# Image not showing using Nsurlconnection Post method

Tags: ios, uitableview, nsurlconnection

[image: nslog using json]I am using `nsurlconnection` in `POST` method and created four array for "see","buy","updated","image".Displayed in `tableviewcell` but "image" not showing. image in "url in png format".

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{


    NSError* error;
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: mutableData
                                           options:kNilOptions
                                             error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@",json);
    sellArray = [json valueForKeyPath:@"BranchByList.sell"];
    buyArray = [json valueForKeyPath:@"BranchByList.buy"];
    updataedArray = [json valueForKeyPath:@"BranchByList.updated"];
    imageArray = [json valueForKeyPath:@"BranchByList.flag_image"];

    [_datad reloadData];
  }
```

tableview delegate methods are:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *) tableView{

    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *) tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [sellArray count];
    return [buyArray count];
    return [updataedArray count];
    return [imageArray count];

    }

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    TableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"path" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.sellbl.text=[sellArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.buylbl.text=[buyArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.updatedlbl.text = [updataedArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.imglbl.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
       return cell;
}

-(void)tableView: (UITableView *) tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  }
```

Comment: can u print this  NSLog(@"%@",json);

Comment: ya printed @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: BranchByList.flag_image --> the image available in your local path or bundle resource

Comment: what `[json valueForKeyPath:@"BranchByList.flag_image"];` statement return?

Comment: i didn't create any local path as well as bundle resource i want to get image from post method response @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: its showing all url for flag_image @Lion

Comment: So you have to download your flag image from url. check my answer. you can sdwebimage for caching the images so it is not download multitime check that github link and use it to increase performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling image like,

```
cell.imglbl.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

It is fine if image is available in your project otherwise you need to download it from url which you getting in response like,

```
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:@"you url"];
  UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
  cell.imglbl.image = img;
```

or you can use [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage), greate third party library to caching the image.

hope this will help :)

Answer (score 1):

You are directly assigning url to image! That will not work at all.
You need to first add the url to NSUrl and then convert the url in to data by using NSData and then assign the data to the image.

To accomplish it add below line of code in your code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

cell.imglbl.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

I'm posting one more example for more understanding. I have a url and i need to display the image from that url to my device. For that m using the below line of code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-9yd6LPL2N6U/VatsUdMffPI/AAAAAAAAAl4/Pq1S6Q20fy0/s1600/hello_world.gif"];

NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

_imgView.image=[UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

Above url is just a random url of a image taken from google.

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add [SDWebImage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

in your project and use this code

```
[cell.imglbl setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]
               placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

instead of

```
cell.imglbl.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
       return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you set not an image to cell.imglbl.image, but the url of it..

```
cell.imglbl.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
```

You can use some third party library like SDWebImage to asynchronous download image.
https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

(Or download it synchronous like this

```
NSData * data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageURL]];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```

)

Also I would recommend you to have a Dictionary to keep already downloaded images, where the keys will be the indexPaths of cells.

Hope it help :)